# Difference between running a SQLAlchemy query in Flask using database configuration or model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have a model in my Flask application like this:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     bar = db.Column(db.String)
```

In a Flask view, I want to query my database to retrieve a record of this type.

In tutorials I've seen people run such a query in two ways: using the `flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` configuration or the model.

## Using `flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy`

The app is set up something like this ...

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['MY_SETTINGS'])
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Then the query in the view looks like this ...

```
my_query = db.session.query(Foo).filter_by(id=some_id)
```

## Using the model

The other way I've seen the query executed is using the model, like this ...

```
import Foo
my_query = Foo.query.filter_by(id=some_id)
```

## What's the difference?

As far as I can tell, the query returns exactly the same thing. So it's hard for me to tell which method I should be using. Or does it make no difference?

What about when it comes to creating and deleting records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same thing, but coming from two different approaches.

The classic SQLAlchemy approach is `db.session.query(Foo).filter_by(id=some_id)`.

Then Flask-SQLAlchemy, among other things, add a property to all models to enable the second approach `Foo.query.filter_by(id=some_id)`.

Additional context (if needed): the second approach mimics the one Django ORM is using, but if you look for SQLAlchemy material on the web you'll mostly find the first approach.

Comment: Thanks @b4stien. I did wonder whether they might just the same thing and down to preference. It makes sense that they might mimic the Django ORM. It's a shame none of the early-stage tutorials I've seen have mentioned this quirk.